# Adding a DNS 'A' record but the TTL (Time to Live) setting is missing (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: windows, dns

I had just created a DNS Server (Windows Server 2019) and added the DNS Role. But after I created a Forward Lookup Zone and try to add a 'A' record for the zone, I found that the TTL setting is missing.

When I add DNS record, the interface is supposed to include the TTL setting. (like the picture below)
[image]

However, the interface eventually came out this way. (see the picture 2)
[image]

I had almost reinstalled everything and tried everything yet still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that I just need to check the "Advanced" in the "View" Menu.
Problem solved!

[image]